# Android: memory leaks due to member variables?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have developed an Android application which consists of a FragmentActivity and several fragments that are called on tab change. 
Each fragment is associated with a view. The logic of the fragment is encapsulated in separate classes. The classes do some
complex calculations. The results of those calculations are to be shown in several text views of the fragment view. Further the fragment
view contains a stop button and the calculations of the classes are to react upon click on the stop button.

My question now is how to organize the access to those view members (text views and stop button) within the classes. Is it safe to
pass the variable associated with each text view as a member variable to the respective class? Here is the respective code that I use.

```
class ClassAFragment extends Fragment 
{
    ClassA classA;
    ...

    public View onCreateView(...) 
    {
        Button stopButton = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById (R.id.btnStop);
        TextView timeLabel = (TextView) this.getActivity().findViewById (R.id.mTimeLabel);

        this.classA = new ClassA();
        this.classA.setAppElements(timeLabel, stopButton);
    }

    ...
}

class ClassA 
{
    TextView mTimeLabel;
    Button mStopButton;

    public void setAppElements(TextView timeLabel, Button stopButton) 
    {
        this.mTimeLabel = timeLabel;
        this.mStopButton = stopButton;

        this.mStopButton.setOnClickListener (this.mStopListener);
    }

    private void showCurrentProgress() 
    {
        this.mTimeLabel.setText("some text");
    }

    public void stop() 
    {
        // react upon stop button being clicked
    }

    OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener ()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v)
        {
            ClassA.this.stop ();
        }
    };

    ...
}
```

Is that code safe with respect to memory leaks? In the official Android documentation I have read that you should not
pass any object that is bound to the App context to a member variable ([Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LocalBroadcastManager or Bus (Otto EventBus for example) to notify UI (Fragment in your case). LocalBroadcastManager is faster (Bus, however, use Reflections which is not chached in pre ICS Android versions and can be slower), but Bus is simplier. Hope it helps.

P.S.  Never put setRetainInstance(true) on UI Fragments.

P.P.S If you do - make sure you properly releasing views in onDestroy()

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to the LocalBroadcastManager. I now use this construct to exchange messages between elements of my application.

Answer (score 1):

They are talking about the problem that you may have if you use `setRetainInstance(true);` in a Fragment   and pass to it a reference to any other object that's associated with a Context.
`setRetainInstance(true);` means that the Fragment will not be destroyed when the Activity is destroyed  and so if you pass to it a reference to a View and destroy the Activity, this will cause a memory leak because the View will not be garbage collected.